SQL - How to Sum every line with record-3
It's dificil ton explain, i want to Sum the 3 last row for every row. An exemple will be better :
ID  VALUE1  RESULT I WANT
===================
1   10   10+5+20 = 35
2   5    5+20+4  = 29
3   20   20+4+50 = 74
4   4    4+50+300 = 354
5   50   50+300+10 = 360
6   300  300+10+15 = 325
7   10   NULL
8   15   NULL

I use Oracle SQL. Thanks
with dummy as 
(
   select 10 as value from dual union all
   select 5 from dual union all
   select 20 from dual union all
   select 4 from dual union all
   select 50 from dual union all
   select 300 from dual union all
   select 10 from dual union ALL
   select 15 from dual 
)
SELECT value, SUM(value) FROM dummy GROUP BY value

i dont have idea to how to process

Do you want to sort and decide which rows to calculate by id or do you use another column for that?

To get result just for rows having 3 values summed - use conditional Count() Over() analytic function:
WITH      --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
  dummy as 
    ( Select 1 "ID", 10 "VALUE" From Dual Union All
      Select 2,   5 From Dual Union All
      Select 3,  20 From Dual Union All
      Select 4,   4 From Dual Union All
      Select 5,  50 From Dual Union All
      Select 6, 300 From Dual Union All
      Select 7,  10 From Dual Union All
      Select 8,  15 From Dual 
)

--    S Q L :
SELECT ID, VALUE, 
       Case When Count(ID) OVER (ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING) = 3
            Then Sum(VALUE) OVER (ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING)
      End "TOTAL_3_ROWS"
FROM dummy;

/*    R e s u l t :
ID  VALUE   TOTAL_3_ROWS
--  -----  -------------
 1     10             35
 2      5             29
 3     20             74
 4      4            354
 5     50            360
 6    300            325
 7     10           null
 8     15           null    */


You can use the Oracle function , "Rows between Current Row and 2 following"
https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-window-functions-rows-clause/ , as follows.
with dummy as 
(
   select 1 as id, 10 as value from dual union all
   select 2 ,5 from dual union all
   select 3, 20 from dual union all
   select 4, 4 from dual union all
   select 5, 50 from dual union all
   select 6, 300 from dual union all
   select 7, 10 from dual union ALL
   select 8, 15 from dual 
)
SELECT id, value, sum(value)
  OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING) sum
   FROM dummy;


Basically correct, but this will return 25 and 15 as sums for the bottom two rows. OP want them rather to be NULL according to their question.
